# Embed React JS Within an Existing Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For the purposes of learning React, and for migrating existing applications to React, I would like to embed a React component within an existing page that is already full of HTML and JS of its own - similar to how [KnockoutJS's `applyBindings` method](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) can target a specific DOM element:

```js
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId'))
```

Unfortunately, every answer I can find related to mixing React with other JS recommends letting React control the rendering of the whole page, and wrapping the other JS in a React component. For example:

- [reddit - r/reactjs - How would you integrate react with non-react code?](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/15gsi91/how_would_you_integrate_react_with_nonreact_code/)
- [React Docs - Integrating with Other Libraries](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)

If this is the only option, it is very limiting, and pretty much restricts React to new green-field projects, not progressive migration of existing projects.

**Can React be used in this way - can it control a specific DOM element and its children, and leave the rest of the page alone?**

**If so, what's the minimal amount of code to do so?** Pretty much every React tutorial starts with `create-react-app`, several React plugins, a build toolchain, etc. All of these things get in the way of both learning React (so many things to learn at once), and using it in existing projects that already have their own existing content and build toolchains.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. React is always initialized on some element inside the body element, and not on the body element itself or the HTML element. Why can't you accomplish what you're after by targeting your element? React doesn't care about what's outside that.

Comment: To clarify, look at [index.html in a boilerplate React app](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/index.html). The target element is just sitting there in a regular ol' HTML page. It could certainly have other stuff around or alongside it.

Comment: @JoséRamírez please don't post flame-bait comments.

Comment: Maybe your question is more about setting up the build process to accommodate this. You'll have to get a bit unconventional to drop a _compiled_ app into a page. If so, revise to be more specific, and to show your attempt. The question is quite broad as it is.

Comment: @DanielSchilling, another thing to consider for you - does your React component need to communicate with the non-React part of your page, and vice-versa?

Comment: @JoséRamírez when considering a framework one has to consider its technical aspects, whether one can hire for it, whether one can *get* hired for it, the availability and quality of the documentation and other help, any existing legacy code one has to interop with, and a whole host of other decision points. You simply can't do justice to the nuance of the choice without understanding the situation of the other, their needs and priorities, and you can't do justice to the decision in the space of a stack overflow answer, much less a comment. That's a blog post (or series).

Comment: @isherwood This is fantastic news. I see the `<div id="app">`. Where is the function call that tells React to put its content inside that element? I assume it's in a different file. I don't see it in `app.js`, but maybe I just don't know what to look for.

Comment: In one file or another you'll find `ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')` or something along those lines. I'm more familiar with the Create-React-App setup, so I'm not exactly sure where it's happening in that repo.

Comment: @rby At the moment, no, I don't have that need. Would that have affected whether this is possible or not? Or does it just complicate things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReactJs and almost every frontend library developed in a way so that one can run multiple apps of same or different library/framework.
Now let's understand How you can use ReactJs to control part of your DOM or can say a part of a view/page.
First step is to load ReactJs and react DOM in your html via a cdn link.
Now it's time to render a component which you had already developed. For your ease, I have created a stackblitz javascript project for your reference. Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gmhwuw?file=index.js,index.html,hello-world.js

But I'm explaining the same here as well. React and ReactDOM will register itself to window object so that you can use both object once script is loaded. We need to understand here about React is that React never take control of whole DOM. It will always control a container and we actually register a container div with React where React will render provided component. So we can say here that a page can have multiple ReactJs applications. Here is code which can use to render a React component inside a div with id react-app

```
// import your component via lazy loading
import('./hello-world.js').then((comp) => {
  // get the container where you want to render
  const reactDiv = document.getElementById('react-app');
  const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(reactDiv);
  reactRoot.render(comp.default());

  // here I'm registering one more react application in another container
  const reactDiv2 = document.getElementById('react-app2');
  const reactRoot2 = ReactDOM.createRoot(reactDiv2);
  reactRoot2.render(comp.default());
});
```

Hope I'm able to resolve your query but please comment if you need any further help

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org).  With it, you can then create micro-frontends in ReactJS that get embedded where needed.